# Why does parse() infer return type only when asserts are included?

Tags: rust, filter-map

Rust beginner so bear with me on this.
Rust documentation includes an example for the basic use of filter_map:

```
let a = ["1", "two", "NaN", "four", "5"];

let mut iter = a.iter().filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok());

assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(1));
assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(5));
assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
```

But I cannot make sense of what parse() returns here? How does parse infer the datatype here? The wierdest part is that if I comment out the 3 asserts, the parse can no longer infer the return type. I tried many variations of parse::Result<i32, something> but they all fail since Result doesn't have an implementation of FromStr.

So, when the asserts are included how come parse can infer the return type? And, more importantly, what is the return type that it infer?

Since I expect parse to return a Result<*,*> type (since that's what ok() operates on), I tried multiple variations of Result but failed since it doesn't implement FromStr

Comment: What would it be able to infer the type from, if you don't use the result for anything?

Comment: @kaya3 I understand that when asserts are included, Rust has some context to infer the return type of parse from. I'm just having trouble figuring out specifically what that return type would be. I just want to know since I'm trying to be precise about my understanding.

Answer (score 6):

The `Some(1)` part is enough for Rust to go "Oh, you want a number!" and figure it out from there. There is no "just parse it" option, there are any number of types that implement the `FromStr` trait and Rust is not going to just pick one randomly.

When you `parse()` without context include what you'd like to parse it into, such as:

```rust
parse::<i32>().ok()
```

Where the type becomes obvious because of a comparison, such as in an assertion, a variable assignment, or a return type, Rust can figure it out for you.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that Rust defaults numbers to `i32` since there are multiple other number types too.